# How to Install Cucumber-Rails under window7 OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, cucumber

I folllow the guid to install cucumber-Rails. When I run "rails generate cucumber:install # Rails 3" , I got an error "Could not find generator cucumber:install."  I have run "bundle install".

Output:

```
Using rake (0.8.7)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.3)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.3)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.1)
Using rack-mount (0.6.13)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.24)
Using actionpack (3.0.3)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.1)
Using treetop (1.4.9)
Using mail (2.2.15)
Using actionmailer (3.0.3)
Using arel (2.0.7)
Using activerecord (3.0.3)
Using activeresource (3.0.3)
Using bundler (1.0.9)
Using mysql2 (0.2.6)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.3)
Using rails (3.0.3)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.
```

**Gemfile:**
 gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

Is there any one can tell doest cucumber support on windows, and how can I install it.

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile` too please?

Comment: Yes, I know my gemfile is wrong. Now I add "gem 'mysql2'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'cucumber-rails'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'win32console'
gem 'capybara'" to my gemfile. But I get another error: " Could not find "step_definitions/web_steps_#.rb.erb" in any of your source paths
. Your current source paths are:
D:/Development/MasterMind/lib/templates/cucumber/install
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-rails-0.3.2/templates/install"